# How can I get sound spectrum data of instruments?

Tags: waves, acoustics, resource-recommendations, fourier-transform, vibrations

I am trying to generate a piano noise by a python function.

```
def piano(phi):
    amps = [...spectrum information...]
    psi = phi
    result = 0
    for a in amps:
        result += a*numpy.sin(psi)
        psi += phi
```

But I can't find anything helpful to fill my spectrum list. Can someone help me with that.

Comment: BTW, there are much more efficient ways to produce a signal from its spectrum. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html

Comment: This might be a better question for [Music.SE].

Comment: Voting to reopen - clearly not a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Use your favourite search engine to find images for "piano spectrum" or "piano harmonics". Or try https://www.pianoharmonics.com/.

Three challenges in creating a realistic piano sound that works for a range of pitches will be:

1. Each harmonic needs its own volume envelope.
2. The number and type of strings used for each note on a piano varies along the keyboard, so the spectrum is not the same for all notes.
3. The dynamics of how a key is struck have a big effect on the sound of a piano note.

Comment: The pianoharmonics.com site (while quite interesting) isn't really relevant to what the OP wants;  it's about a musical technique in which the player touches the strings to dampen certain modes of the string while letting other modes be excited.  I don't see where/if it has the amplitudes of the various modes for a "normally" vibrating string.

Comment: Also:  your point about the envelope (the attack and decay of the sound) is an important one.  The piano might not be the easiest instrument to simulate in this way;  IIRC wind instruments are "easier" to simulate without taking the envelope into account.